# Antlr Lexer back track in complex file parsing

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

We are using ANTLR for parsing complex file structure and then creating java objects to do certain activity.

Till now every line in the file used to start with an identifier. For example: 
LINE1.....\n
LINE2.....\n
EOF

Now with new requirements, the identifier of the lines i.e., LINE1 etc. can occur in any part of the line. And the characters in the identifier can occur as well.

Below is the grammar that I tried, but it fails because of Lexer not back tracking and I am not sure how to make it work.

```
file : line* EOF;

line : (line_one  line_two* ) NEWLINE?;

line_one : field+ LINE1_ID field* {
   System.out.println("got line_one:" + $line_one.text);
};

line_two  : field+ LINE2_ID field* {
   System.out.println("got line_two:" + $line_two.text);
};

field : (FIELD | SKIP_ID )+;

LINE1_ID : 'LINE1' ;

LINE2_ID  : 'LINE2' ;

SKIP_ID :   'L';

FIELD : FCHAR+;
fragment
FCHAR   :  ~('\r' | '\n' | 'L' );
NEWLINE: ('\r' '\n' | '\r' | '\n');
```

I am not an expert in Antlr or writing grammars, any pointer or help is really appreciated. P.S. Antlr version used is 3.4 and we cannot upgrade it to 4.

Example of a file in use (fixed length format):

```
HEADER 1001 SERIALNO 0001
1    GROUP START 001 1002
2    1003 CUST 550000001 15-12-2013 
3    1003 CUST 550000002 20-11-2013 
4    1003 CUST 550000003 19-12-2013
5    GROUP END 001 1004
6    GROUP START 002 1002
7    1003 CUST 570000001 15-12-2013 
8    1003 CUST 570000002 20-11-2013 
9    1003 CUST 570000003 19-12-2013
10   GROUP END 002 1004
11   FILE  END 1005
```

The identifier of each line is marked by 1001, 1002 and so on. 1001 is header of the file and 1002 marks begin of a group while 1004 marks the end of a group. 1003 represents the actual records and 1005 marks end of the file.
The occurrence of line identifier position may vary from line to line but occurrence position is fixed with in a line i.e., if the same line is occurring multiple times as in case of CUST record, the position is fixed as 5 (assuming first char is at position 0)

The problem with lexer is once it identifies 100 it assumes that is always try to match with header record and if it fails it doesn't back track and also those characters i.e., 100 gets lost if $line.text is used to fetch the line that is already consumed.

In the above example i used numbers to identify a line but the identifier can be a alpha numeric and valid characters are that of UTF-8 not just ASCII.

The input to above grammar is:

```
 ABCDLINE1aaaaFGHA\n
 aaabbbBCLINE2XYZ\n
 LINELINELINE2PQR\n
 LIN QRSTLINE2ABC579\n
```

The Output of the program when parser.file() is invoked:

```
got line_one:ABCDLINE1aaaaFGHA
line 2:8 mismatched input 'LINE2' expecting LINE1_ID
line 3:0 no viable alternative at character 'L'
line 2:16 mismatched input '\r\n' expecting LINE1_ID
line 3:4 no viable alternative at character 'L'
line 3:8 mismatched input 'LINE2' expecting LINE1_ID
line 4:0 no viable alternative at character 'L'
line 3:16 mismatched input '\r\n' expecting LINE1_ID
line 4:8 mismatched input 'LINE2' expecting LINE1_ID
line 4:19 mismatched input '\r\n' expecting LINE1_ID
```

Thanks

Comment: @BartKiers, Added example, input and output to the above grammar.

Comment: It looks to me that you've just started writing a grammar without trying to get familiar with the basics of ANTLR. I suggest you pick up a copy of the [The Definitive ANTLR Reference](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference) and start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Bart, but do you think it is feasible to achieve the above using ANTLR3 or should i look in some other direction to handle?

Comment: Sure, but you might be trying to put too much logic in parser rules: it is often a better idea to match a bit loosely and then walk over the generated AST for further validation. Also be sure to read up on how tokens are created: ANTLR's lexer always tries to match as much as possible. Good luck.